# Ajax in iframe not updating the iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

I've searched high and low for an answer to this question but have yet to find a similar question or an answer.  I apologize if this is a "re-ask".

Essentially my problem is this:  I have an iframe inside of my parent page, and inside the iframe is a php page that includes my .js file containing my AJAX.  I want button clicks in the iframe to create an AJAX request and update the iframe.  As far as I know I have it all set up correctly but when I attempt to echo my $_POST (I've tried GET too) variables to test them they never change.  Here's my code:

Parent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style = "height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <head>
        <title>Employee Web Service</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="lib/css/main.css" />
        <script src="lib/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body style = "height: 100%;">
        <div id = "header">
            <img src = "images/header.png" id = "headerLogo">
        </div>
        <div id = "nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href = "home.php" target = "content">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Modules</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href = "test.php?id=1" target = "content">Module 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "test.php?id=2" target = "content">Module 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "test.php?id=3" target = "content">Module 3</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "test.php?id=4" target = "content">Module 4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href = "scores.php" target = "content">Scores</a></li>
                <li><a href = "calendar.php" target = "content">Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href = "logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id = "content">
            <iframe src = "home.php" name = "content" id = "frameContent"></iframe>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#frameContent').load(function(){
                        $('#frameContent').contents().find('head').append('<link href="lib/css/iframe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

test.php inside Iframe:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['begin'])){
        $test = true;
        echo($_POST['begin']);
    } else if (isset($_POST['backToSlides'])){
        echo($_POST['backToSlides']);
    }
?>
<head>
    <script src="lib/scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "lib/scripts/testScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "startTest" <?php if(isset($test)){echo 'style = "visibility: hidden; disabled: true;"';}?> >
        <h1>Test <?php echo $id; ?></h1>
        <form id = "begin">
            <input type = "submit" name = "backToSlides" value = "Go back" style = "background: #B9090B;">
            <input type = "submit" name = "begin" value = "Start Test" style = "background: #09913A;">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id = "testContent"></div>
</body>
```

testScript.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name = "backToSlides"], input[name = "begin"]').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        post = $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/test.php",
            type: "POST", 
            data: post, //Data purposely not serialized due to the way submit-type input field values are handled
            success: function(){
                console.log("Processing request...");},
            error: function(){
                console.log("Error submitting request");}
        });
    });
});
```

This ALWAYS calls the success function, but I never see the value of the submit buttons in the post data.  I know they're being passed into the ajax call properly because I've tried calling alert($(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val()) and I get the expected result of "key=value".

A speedy response is greatly appreciated!

Comment: do really *need* an iframe here?

Comment: Does this happen when you open `test.php` directly? I'd also set `post` as `post = {}; post[this.name] = this.value`

Comment: The iframe is loading `home.php`, not `test.php`.

Comment: @Barmar I assumed OP meant after clicking one of the *Module* links

Comment: @Phil I have the same issue when linking to test.php directly.  Haven't tried changing the post variable yet, I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @Barmar Phil is correct.  The iframe loads the home.php page initially, but I'm currently writing the test.php page which loads after clicking one of the module drop-down items.

Comment: @Phil I changed the variable to `post = {}; post[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();` which gives me the desired object {name: value} but I still have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed the iframe to a div and used the jquery .load() function instead

on the parent page:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            tar = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#content").load(tar);
        );
    );
</script>
```

I could just turn all the `<a>` tags into `<div>` tags that change the cursor to a pointer on mouse-over instead so I don't have to prevent the default action and scan the 'href' attribute, but this does the trick for now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the default browser  submittal of the form, otherwise since you are submitting to same url it will just refresh the iframe page

```
$('input[name = "backToSlides"], input[name = "begin"]').click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    /* ajax */

})
```

Comment: So it seems I forgot to add this bit to my original post.  event.preventDefault(); is there, and it's still not working.

Comment: use browser console network tab to see if ajax request made . If it is, see what's sent , status etc. What is being logged in console?

Comment: Hmm ok, so I'm noticing something weird.  (Using Chrome) in the PREVIEW and RESPONSE tabs it shows that the echo and the parameters are being set and received properly, but on the actual page the echos don't show up.

Comment: because it is invalid html to echo text in `head`. Need to rethink what you are returning

Comment: I replaced the echos with var_dump()'s and still nothing.  Also, if you notice, I'm checking in the startTest DIV if $test is set, and if it is then hide the div.  In the preview the div is hidden properly, on the main page it is not.

Comment: where's the code that would insert the response? You aren't using any argument in `success` above to receive any data should be something like `success: function(data){ console.log(data)}`

Comment: Doesn't the ajax just make a `POST` to test.php?  So I should be able to access the variables in test.php just by checking `if(isset($_POST['data'])){}` Correct?  Putting data in my success block just prints the data to my log, not sure how that helps me.

Comment: there is no param `data` being sent...look at request again in console network tab. Really not sure what your objective is now. If you plan to receive data back you need the argument in success

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken here but doesn't 
`var post = stuff;$.ajax{
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: post
  }`
 send the variable 'post' to the url "url"?

Comment: yes , but that is a string in your case with either of the submit button names and it's value

Comment: The string seems to be working the way it should though, according to the preview and response tabs as I mentioned earlier.  Right now, when a user clicks on "Start Test", the title and buttons should get hidden and the test should be var_dumped (which the preview correctly shows).  The real page, however, does not show this.  So I'm not sure it's a problem with sending a string.  Unless sending a string does in fact not work and I need to send an object instead (something like `{name: value}` perhaps?)

Comment: easier to let jQuery serialize object but string is valid as long as it is encoded proprly

Comment: Yeah, I did a bunch of research prior and you can't serialize a form that contains only a button, so you have to do it manually.  I turned it into an object which is doing the same thing as the string (shows up properly in the preview, not on the actual site).

PS. I really appreciate your constant dialogue, thanks :)